# SendGrid throwing a SMTPAuthenticationError on Heroku with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

**This is a Rails 4 App**

**production.rb**

```
Depot::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :user_name            => 'my_app@heroku.com',
    :password             => 'my_password',
    :domain               => "my_domain.heroku.com",
    :address              => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    :port                 => 587,
    :authentication       => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end
```

**orders_controller.rb**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:new, :create]

  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    if @cart.line_items.empty?
      redirect_to store_url, notice: "Your cart is empty"
      return
    end

    @order = Order.new
  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
        session[:cart_id] = nil
        OrderNotifier.received(@order).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to store_url, notice:
          'Thank you for your order.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1
  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /orders/1
  # DELETE /orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @order.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:name, :notes, :email, :location)
    end
end
```

**order_notifier.rb**

```
class OrderNotifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "Drew Wyatt <app17490328@heroku.com>"

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.order_notifier.received.subject
  #
  def received(order)
    @order = order

    mail to: order.email, subject: 'Store Order Confirmation'
  end

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.order_notifier.shipped.subject
  #
  def shipped(order)
    @order = order

    mail to: order.email, subject: 'Order Has Shipped'
  end
end
```

**Excerpt from Heroku Logs**

```
2013-08-14T16:07:13.195968+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/orders host=mightywash-supply-store.herokuapp.com fwd="65.182.83.157" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=683ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-08-14T16:07:13.192856+00:00 app[web.1]: Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
2013-08-14T16:07:13.192856+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-08-14T16:07:13.193066+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:43:in `block in create'
2013-08-14T16:07:13.193066+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:39:in `create'
2013-08-14T16:07:13.193066+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-14T16:07:13.193066+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-14T16:07:02.417721+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/line_items?product_id=1 host=mightywash-supply-store.herokuapp.com fwd="65.182.83.157" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=444ms status=200 bytes=950
```

At this point I feel like I have tried a million mailer combinations using (and not using) sendgrid - any ideas?